# AWS EMR Notebook not entering into "Running" state

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jupyter-notebook, aws-api-gateway, amazon-emr

While starting the notebook which is on AWS EMR cluster using boto3 it's not entering into 'running' state so I'm not sure whether my script is working properly or not. Note - I'm calling boto3 functions from a lambda function and invoking this lambda function using api gateway. Is there any way I can verify whether my notebook ran successfully or not?

Cluster state - waiting, Notebook state - Stopped, Notebook is attached to cluster.

`
import json
import boto3
import time

def lambda_handler(event, context):
# TODO implement
client = boto3.client('emr')
cluster_state = client.describe_cluster(ClusterId='XXXX')
print("Cluster state - \n")
print(cluster_state)
response = client.start_notebook_execution(
EditorId='XXXX',
RelativePath='XXXX',
ExecutionEngine={'XXXX'},
ServiceRole='XXXX'
)

```
execution_id = response["NotebookExecutionId"]
print("========== Execution ID ==========")
print(execution_id)

describe_response = client.describe_notebook_execution(
    NotebookExecutionId=execution_id
)
print("Describing notebook execution \n")
print(describe_response)

list_response = client.list_notebook_executions()
print("Notebook execution details: \n")
for execution in list_response['NotebookExecutions']:
    print(execution)
    print("\n")

print("Sleeping for 5 sec...")
time.sleep(5)

client.stop_notebook_execution(NotebookExecutionId=execution_id)

describe_response = client.describe_notebook_execution(
    NotebookExecutionId=execution_id
)
print(describe_response)`
```

Cloudwatch logs -
'Status': 'STARTING'
'Status': 'STOPPED'
'Status': 'FINISHED'
'Status': 'STOPPED'
'Status': 'STOPPED'
'Status': 'STOPPED'
'Status': 'STOPPED'
'Status': 'FINISHED'
'Status': 'FINISHED'
'Status': 'FAILED'

Answer (score 0):

Notebook security group sg-0055653XXXXXbf01c does not have an egress rule to connect with the master security group sg-0055653XXXXXbf01c. Please fix the security group or use the default option.